# How can I kill the parent process from a child thread spawned by cluster.fork?

Tags: node.js

An error gets thrown in a child thread created by `cluster.fork()` and I want to kill the parent (and in doing so, kill all other sibling threads.

How can I do this from within the child thread (`cluster.isWorker === true`:`true`)?

Comment: How about  sending a message to the parent telling it to do `process.exit()`?  Then, you could have a more orderly shut-down.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes normally that's valid. That's good if you're going for highly scalable code, but short one-off solutions have their value sometimes too right? If I were going to send the message to the parent I'd want to develop a debugger class that gets required in to each class and listenes for error events, then triggers the message rather than write that in everywhere I handle errors. Alternatively I think we can just use a more simple-minded one-liner to kill the parent. So the solution I I posted as an answer is good for quick one-off code fixes.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm just multithreading some data processing from one form to another. A quick n dirty solution is preferable in this particular case. But you are right about that being the cleaner solution.

Comment: I don't understand what the big deal is with sending a message to the parent and adding a one line event handler to the parent.  There's no big overhead involved to do it a better way.  Architectural shortcuts have a habit of accumulating and then at some point you've got a mountain of them in your project.  As you can tell, I'm not a fan of the quick and dirty way of doing things when there's a simple, cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. From within a worker, I can't seem to access `process` globally, but this seems to work:

```
cluster.worker.process.kill(cluster.worker.process.ppid)
```